# Stationary measure for irreducible aperiodic markov chains

Tags: probability, matrices, limits, discrete-mathematics, markov-chains

I have a little question to ask as a beginner in Markov Chain theory.

Considering an irreducible aperiodic Discrete Time Markov Chain $X_n$ with transition matrix $P$ and finite state space (discrete).

In this situation, we know by a theorem that the law of the Markov Chain converges to the stationary measure as follows. Considering $\mu_0$ the initial distribution of $X_n$ and $\pi$ the stationary measure, we have
$$lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} \mu_0P^n=\pi$$

I was wondering if we could consider the following. By previous theorem, we know the convergence. However can we say that therefore **there exists a finite N such that $\prod_{i=1}^NP^i=Q$ with Q having the stationary measure in each row**.

Thank you very much for your help.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite. Consider $ 0 < ε < 1/2$ and
$$
P = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1-\varepsilon  & \varepsilon  \\
 \varepsilon  & 1-\varepsilon  \\
\end{array}
\right),
$$
for which the stationary measure would be $ π = (1/2, 1/2)$. E.g. by diagonalizing $P$, we can compute
$$
P^n = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} (1-2 \varepsilon )^n+\frac{1}{2} &
   \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} (1-2 \varepsilon )^n \\
 \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} (1-2 \varepsilon )^n & \frac{1}{2} (1-2
   \varepsilon )^n+\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right),
$$
so no power of $P$ equals $Q$, the matrix whose rows all equal $π = (1/2, 1/2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What conditions could guarantee to have a finite N such that the product of transition matrices equals $Q$?

Comment: I'm unable to come up with something smart here, unfortunately.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is a very difficult question that you are asking. Essentially you want to whether there is a way to do a perfect simulation with this transition matrix. In MCMC, some of these are studied and there is a algorithm called "Propp–Wilson algorithm" - but that's simulating not forward in time, but backwards in time. You can have a look at the book  "Finite Markov Chains and Algorithmic Applications" by Olle Haggstrom.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I will have a look. Thank you for your help as well.